# How @FeignClient Map Object returned from the Callee Service

Tags: rest, jackson, spring-cloud-feign

I created two simple RESTful services(***rent-management-service, car-management-service***), in the ***rent-service*** I'm calling a `GET` method of ***car-service*** with the help of `@FeignClient` which returns an instance of `Car` class. This `Car` class only resides in ***car-service***.
So in order to map this object in ***rent-service*** `@FeignClient`Proxy interface's method, I've created a class named `CarProxy` which has exactly the same fields and everything as `Car` class. And this mapping works fine.
My question is How this mapping happens even if classes are Two different? Is `@FeignClient` or `Jackson` maps this based on the field names of the class?
And is it OK to create Proxy classes for objects `@FeignClient`Proxy methods returning? Or is it better to make `@Controller`methods to returns objects in `HashSet` or `HashMap` instead of using a Custom class like `Car`?

```java
//Car class Only in Car-management-service
@Entity
@Table(name = "CAR")
public class Car {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "CAR_ID")
    private Long carId;

    @Column(name = "REG_NUM")
    private String regNumber;

    @Column(name = "BRAND")
    private String brand;

    @Column(name = "MODEL")
    private String model;

//Getter,Setter,Constructor below
}
```

```java
//Controller in car-management-service which returns Car object
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/car-service")
public class CarInfoController {
    @Autowired
    CarService service;

    @GetMapping(path = "/getCarInfo/{Id}")
    public Car getCarDetails(@PathVariable Long Id) {
        if (Id == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Id is Null");
        return service.findCarById(Id);
    }
}
```

```java
//FeignClient interface in rent-management-service which calls car-service GET endpoint
@FeignClient(name = "car-management-service", url = "localhost:8100/car-service")
public interface CarManagementServiceProxy {
    @GetMapping(path = "/getCarInfo/{Id}")
    public CarProxy getCarDetails(@PathVariable("Id") Long Id);
}
```

```java
//CarProxy class in rent-service which is a clone to Car class in car-service
public class CarProxy {

    private Long carId;
    private String regNumber;
    private String brand;
    private String model;

//Getter,Setter,Constructor below
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How this mapping happens even if classes are Two different? Is
>   @FeignClient or Jackson maps this based on the field names of the
>   class?

`Jackson` library which is used behind the scene does not care how `JSON` payload was created and from which class serialized. If `JSON` payload fits to class you want to deserialize to, it just does it. If not - throws an exception. If you do not want to create a `POJO` you can use `Map` for `JSON Object` and array or `List` for `JSON Array` respectively.

You can use [DefaultTyping](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.html) and `Jackson` will try to create the same classes which were used to before to serialize `JSON`.

For more info, take a look at:

- [Intro to the Jackson ObjectMapper](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial)
- [Serialization and Deserialization with ObjectMapper](https://thepracticaldeveloper.com/2018/07/31/java-and-json-jackson-serialization-with-objectmapper/)

> Is it OK to create Proxy classes for objects @FeignClientProxy methods
>   returning? Or is it better to make @Controllermethods to returns
>   objects in HashSet or HashMap instead of using a Custom class like
>   Car?

To decouple two services from each other it is safe to create two separate `Car` classes in each service. Mostly they are not the same, because **car-management-service** could have more fields in `Car` class to handle some internal operations and expose only some in `API`. Also, different `API` methods could return different views of `Car` class.

Using maps instead of `POJO` creates really ugly code which is hard to maintain. You should avoid that if you pass objects to other layers of your app.

See also:

- [Don't Share Libraries among Microservices](https://phauer.com/2016/dont-share-libraries-among-microservices/)